# Error "The requested URL was not found on this server" en Laravel y CPanel

Tags: php, laravel-6, cpanel, error404

Hola tengo una pregunta subí un proyecto de *Laravel* en *CPanel* en un sub-dominio y me arroja un error que me dice que no consigue la URL:

> Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an >ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Parece que es un error de tu hosting. Talvez si agregas captura de pantalla se te podria ayudar mejor.

Comment: capture de que parte ?